# how can I dynamically change value(Profile name) on ASP.NET MVC nav bar and keep it static across all actions?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I am working on Authentication and after a successful login, I want to display the user's name on the nav bar. I have used a static field to hold the user's name and display it using `@ViewBag`, the problem is when a route changes viewbag becomes null. That requires me to update viewbag with a static field in every action. So is there any other way to do this without updating viewbag in every action? Any method to avoid code repetition will be appreciated.

Controller: Dashboard

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
        // Get session
        string id = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("AccoountId");
        
        // Find user | loggedin user
        var account = await userService.GetAccount(id);
        
        Profile.Firstname = account.Firstname;
        Profile.Lastname = account.Lastname;
    
        ViewBag.Name =  $"{Profile.Firstname.ToString().Substring(0, 1)}.{Profile.Lastname}";
    
        var report = userService.GetReportAsync().Result;
    
        if (report == null)
            return RedirectToAction("UnAuthorize", "Home");
    
        return View(report);
}
```

View: _layout

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - Contact Manager Portal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#openModalBtn").click(function () {
                $("#myModal").modal('show');
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                @*<a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">ContactsManager.Web</a>*@

                <div>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                            aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>

                    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Reports</a>
                            </li>

                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="User" asp-action="Index">Clients</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div style="gap:.9em; display:flex">
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "User", FormMethod.Get))
                    {
                        <div class="input-group mb-6 d-flex" style="gap:.6em">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="query" placeholder="Search Contacts">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Search</button>
                        </div>
                    }

                    <button id="openModalBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-cloud-plus" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 5.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v1.5H10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H8.5V10a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V8.5H6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h1.5V6a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5" />
                            <path d="M4.406 3.342A5.53 5.53 0 0 1 8 2c2.69 0 4.923 2 5.166 4.579C14.758 6.804 16 8.137 16 9.773 16 11.569 14.502 13 12.687 13H3.781C1.708 13 0 11.366 0 9.318c0-1.763 1.266-3.223 2.942-3.593.143-.863.698-1.723 1.464-2.383m.653.757c-.757.653-1.153 1.44-1.153 2.056v.448l-.445.049C2.064 6.805 1 7.952 1 9.318 1 10.785 2.23 12 3.781 12h8.906C13.98 12 15 10.988 15 9.773c0-1.216-1.02-2.228-2.313-2.228h-.5v-.5C12.188 4.825 10.328 3 8 3a4.53 4.53 0 0 0-2.941 1.1z" />
                        </svg>
                        Upload
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div>

                    <p style="margin:0px">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-person" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path d="M8 8a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6m2-3a2 2 0 1 1-4 0 2 2 0 0 1 4 0m4 8c0 1-1 1-1 1H3s-1 0-1-1 1-4 6-4 6 3 6 4m-1-.004c-.001-.246-.154-.986-.832-1.664C11.516 10.68 10.289 10 8 10s-3.516.68-4.168 1.332c-.678.678-.83 1.418-.832 1.664z" />
                        </svg>
                        @ViewBag.Name

                    </p>
                </div>

            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">

            

            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container" style="text-align:center; font-size:.9rem">
            &copy;Copyright Reserved @DateTime.Now.Year | Contact Manager | <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/dist/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As you are using `ViewBag` which is not data persistent so it would be null, you should use of session so that you can persist as long as you want. After your login  you can set your session variable with the profile name and then access it in layout nav, you can do like this `HttpContext.Session.SetString("UserName", $"{Profile.Firstname.ToString().Substring(0, 1)}.{Profile.Lastname}");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have used a static field to hold the user's name and display it
> using @ViewBag, the problem is when a route changes viewbag becomes
> null.

Well, right you are and the result you are getting is expected. Becuase, ViewBag, TempData, ViewData all are data non persistent, means, once you load  view, the data would be no more available next time. So this wouldn't keep your login user name within the layout page once you switch the page or change the route.

> So is there any other way to do this without updating viewbag in every
> action?

To directly answer your question, yes there are. In fact, a lot of ways to handle this issue. But the most convenient for your scenario is using [asp.net core session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-8.0#set-and-get-session-values). Becuase, you are already using `HttpContext.Session` so you can create another session varible for that.

In .NET session, as you know, we have [SetString(ISession, String, String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.sessionextensions.setstring?view=aspnetcore-8.0) and [GetString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.sessionextensions.setstring?view=aspnetcore-8.0) which would keep your profile name, you can set the duration how long you want to keep the data, and most importantly, its persistent, no matter, you change the route, page or anything it would keep the value without reaload or anything.

Let's have a look in practice how we can use that within your scenaroi:

Controller:

Within your controller, you can do as following:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var firstName = "Tipe";
    var LastName = "Farid Uddin";

    HttpContext.Session.SetString("UserName", $"{firstName} {LastName}");
    return View();
}
```

Layout:

In order to access the name within your layout page, first of all at the very top on your layout page, include this line:

```
@inject IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor
```

Now update your layout page as following:

```
<div>
     <p style="margin:0px">
         <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-person" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
             <path d="M8 8a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6m2-3a2 2 0 1 1-4 0 2 2 0 0 1 4 0m4 8c0 1-1 1-1 1H3s-1 0-1-1 1-4 6-4 6 3 6 4m-1-.004c-.001-.246-.154-.986-.832-1.664C11.516 10.68 10.289 10 8 10s-3.516.68-4.168 1.332c-.678.678-.83 1.418-.832 1.664z" />
         </svg>
        
         @(httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("UserName") ?? "")
     </p>
 </div>
```

Program.cs:

Within your program.cs file you should register Session middleware referece as following:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
   
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);
   
});
```

and Use the Session:

```
app.UseSession();
```

Output:

[image]

**Note:** You can customize your session Options based on your requirements. As told you earlier, couple of ways available what you are trying to achieve. In addition, please [refer to this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-8.0#session-state) if you want to study more.